# JQuery unobtrusively get link by unique id

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a comment form for posts on my website. I would like to make a link that when clicked displays a comment form.  In turn, there will be multiple posts per page so each link will be unique.  I want to use unobtrusive javascript to accomplish this, but I am confused on how to use unique ids with JQuery.

For example:

```
<a href="#" id="comment_1234">Comment</a>

<div id="comment_form_1234">
    form goes here
</div>

$("#comment_?").click(function(){
    $("#comment_form_?").show();
});
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks you,

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would structure the HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" class="comment" data-id="1234">Comment</a>

<div class="comment_form" data-id="1234">
    form goes here
</div>
```

With this script:

```
$(".comment").on('click', function(){
    $('.comment_form[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: in newer jQuery versions you can use `$(this).data('id')` instead of `$(this).attr('data-id')`. Just nicer to look at...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use $(this).next(.comment_form').show(); ?

Comment: Using `.data()` only works if you generate the DOM in JavaScript. Typically you'd just output the HTML on the serverside.

`.next()` should work great though!

Answer (score 0):

You could try -

```
$('a[id^="comment_"]').click(function(){
    $("#" + this.id.replace("comment_","comment_form_")).show();
});
```

That should fire for all of your comment links, you can then manipulate the id of the clicked element to show the relevant form.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Zjs92/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have

```
<a href="#" class="comment" data-id="1234">Comment</a>
```

and a single form area

```
<div class="comment_form" data-id="">
</div>
```

using jQuery like this

```
$('.comment').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.comment_form').attr('data-id', $(this).attr('data-id')).show();

    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
});
```